# Unable to access custom setting property obtained outside of Method()

Tags: apex, trigger, customsetting

In below class , I am unable to access the custom setting when it is queried outside of a method:

```
public class atestclass{

    customsetting_Configs__c configs = customsetting_Configs__c.getValues('Custom_Setting_Name');
    public static void aMethod(){
       String hyperLink = configs.Field__C;    // Variable does not exist: configs.Field__C
    }
}
```

***Works fine:***

```
public class atestclass{


    public static void aMethod(){
        customsetting_Configs__c configs = customsetting_Configs__c.getValues('Custom_Setting_Name');
        String hyperLink = configs.Field__C;    // Variable does not exist: configs.Field__C
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only access static variables from static methods:

```
static MySetting__c record;
static void doStuff()
{
    // can access records here
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew that I cannot access non static variable from static. But did not see that a custom setting can be declared as static also.

Comment: Any property can...

Comment: duh , So dum that I missed such a small thing.